# UnsatisfiedLinkError For Non-Maven Jar Dependency in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jar, war, resteasy

So I have an external jar dependency a Java RESTEasy application that is non-maven. So, I included this plugin in my `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>install-external-non-maven-jar</id>
<phase>clean</phase>
<configuration>
<repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
<groupId>com.dynamsoft</groupId>
<artifactId>barcode</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<file>${project.basedir}/lib/com.dynamsoft.barcode.jar</file>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<generatePom>true</generatePom>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>install-file</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

and have added this dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.dynamsoft</groupId>
<artifactId>barcode</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

All of that works fine... if I force an artifact reload with maven, it seems to find it fine and it even includes `barcode-1.0.jar` in `nis.war/WEB-INF/lib/` which contains the classes I need (I've even gone in and manually checked the jar addition). Whenever I call on the dependent class though, I get this stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.dynamsoft.barcode.BarcodeReader.nativeCreateInstance()J
com.dynamsoft.barcode.BarcodeReader.nativeCreateInstance(Native Method)
com.dynamsoft.barcode.BarcodeReader.<init>(BarcodeReader.java:33)
com.corista.nis.web.resources.Slides.getLabelDataForSlideByID(Slides.java:507)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

From what I can put together, it think it may just not be able to find the library files. The library files are included in the dependent jar file though, so I'm not entirely convinced... any thoughts?

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkError refers to a missing native library (DLL, SO), not a jar. The jar alone will only work for compilation purposes. You will have to revisit the documentation of the product and see what native libraries you need.

Comment: @Gimby There are several native library files in the jar itself. Additionally, I've added the system location of the library files to my java.library.path and called on System.loadLibrary() on the libraries which it lists.

Comment: Hm, I didn't get a notification so this response is very late. It seems the jar as you describe is intended to be loaded through JNA or some other technology which will extract the natives before loading them (so your manual call to loadLibrary should not be necessary). I assume the BarcodeReader class will do that then, so the only thing I can think of is a mismatch between the CPU architecture for the runtime and the natives. I.E.: it may only specifically work on either a 32 bits or 64 bits runtime.